# MIDL import keyword generates to much compiler output

Tags: midl

Each import in .idl file generate following output:
*64 bit Processing file.idl*

Because of that I have two pages of output for every idl file processed. Is there any way to reduce this flood? Ideal for me is that same what c++ compiler do - only one line of output with input file name if there was no warnings or errors.

I have tried /nologo and /W0 switches, but it didn't helped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately those printf lines are unconditional - they are always printed out.